# Change next <td> text with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors, row

I have grid row scheme like:

```
<tr>
    <td>110</td>
    <td><input class="client-chb" name="checkedRecords" type="checkbox" value="110" title="checkedRecords"></td>
    <td>Some name</td>
    <td>Some other name</td>
    <td>1.1.2012</td>
</tr>
```

I have one function where I get all selected checkboxes, get their values and send to the server via ajax.

But I want just before I make that ajax post, to get 3 & 4 `<td>` and change text style like:

```
<td><b>Some name</b></td>
```

I need this vice versa. Or to be more clear, this is "mark as read" and "mark as unread" message inbox.

```
function MarkAsUnread() {
    var idata = new Array();
    $(".client-chb:checked").each(function() {
        var test = $(this);
        // maybe here, test -> find next td -> change text
        idata.push($(this).val());
    });
    //other logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
function MarkAsUnread() {
    var idata = new Array();
    $(".client-chb:checked").each(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td').slice(2, 4).wrapInner('<b/>')
        idata.push($(this).val());
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this can be simplified to `$("tr td").slice(2, 4).wrap("<b>");`.

Comment: @pimvdb `wrap()` will wrap the `TD`s not their text? am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I meant `.wrapInner`.

Comment: i added some class so i made like $(this).closest('tr').find('td.ch-bold1').wrapInner('<b/>');

Answer (score 0):

You have iterating over input elements wrapped within TD, so first you want to et the parent of your input element(checkbox) and the perform next..

Like,

```
function MarkAsUnread() {
    var idata = new Array();
    $(".client-chb:checked").each(function() {
        var test = $(this).parent();
        var next1 = test.next();
        var next2 = test.next().next();
        idata.push(next1.val());
        idata.push(next2.val());
    });
    //other logic
}
```

To get or set contents of next and next to next TDs use next1.val() and next2.val()

Comment: "_UPDATING the revious comment...._" is not an answer. If you update something, leave it for people to see until you will actually update it.